# Restore AnimationController State Upon returning to Page

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to preserve the state of a Countdown Timer (example given below) so that when I navigate to the Countdown Timer page, start the countdown, say at 10, then pause it, say at 7, and navigate away from the Timer and back, the Timer shows 7, the paused time, vs the initial state of 10.

In separate code, not shown here, I tried using PageStorageBucket + PageStorage to store the AnimationController, and restore this in InitState, but that did not work.

What is the best way to restore the state of the Animation Controller after leaving/returning back to the page it is on?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text("AnimatonController"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Counter()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterText extends AnimatedWidget {
  CounterText({Key key, this.animation})
      : super(key: key, listenable: animation);
  Animation<int> animation;

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text(
      animation.value.toString(),
      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 200.0),
    );
  }
}

class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new _CounterState();
}

class _CounterState extends State<Counter> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  static const int startCount = 10;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: new Duration(seconds: startCount),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(_controller.isAnimating ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller.isAnimating
                  ? _controller.stop()
                  : _controller.forward();
            });
          }),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Center(
          child: new CounterText(
            animation: new StepTween(
              begin: startCount,
              end: 0,
            ).animate(_controller),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to preserve the state of the controller would be to use a [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Create a class to store your controller state e.g.,

```
class CounterStateModel {
  AnimationController _controller;
  int startCount = 10;
}
```

Wrap your App in a Provider

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<CounterStateModel>(
      builder: (context) => CounterStateModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
```

Then in your _CounterState class, use this provider to save/retrieve your controller

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CounterStateModel _counterStateModel = Provider.of<CounterStateModel>(context);

  if (_counterStateModel._controller == null) {
    _counterStateModel._controller = new AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: new Duration(seconds: _counterStateModel.startCount),
  );
  _counterStateModel._controller = _controller;
  } else {
    _controller = _counterStateModel._controller;
  }

  return new Scaffold(
```

Full code is [here](https://pastebin.com/RWV1v9V8)